# Rademacher expansions for weight 1/2

Tags: nt.number-theory, circle-method

In a famous paper Rademacher used the circle theorem to give a formula for the fourier coefficients of the partition function  $1/f(q)$ where $f(q) = \prod_{n=1}(1-q^n)$, and in another paper he gave the coefficients of the j-invariant function $j(q)$. In these cases he was dealing with modular forms of weight -1/2 and 0 respectively.

My question is: is there a known formula for the Fourier coefficients of  $j(q) f(q)$?

This seems to be a modular function of weight 1/2, and the usual circle method only works for non-positive weight. On the other hand, it seems hard to imagine that this does not exist in the literature. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a nice review of Radmemacher sums and series for both modular and mock modular forms here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3066

This review includes formulae for the coefficients of modular functions of weight $1/2$.

Comment: Dear jah, thank you! I will look at it in detail. Do they give explicit formulas for weight  1/2? [I find the language of the review a bit hard to follow, sorry!]

Comment: Theorems 2.7 and 3.2 in that reference refer to weight $1/2$. And yes, there is an equation for the coefficients in terms of a sum involving Bessel functions and Kloosterman sums. Note that in general the Rademacher series produces a mock modular form of weight $1/2$. It is only when the invariance group has genus zero that it produces an actual modular rather than mock modular form.

Comment: Thank you Jah! sorry, two more questions: .- In the case above the invariance group is that of the Dedeking eta function, right? I guess this is the *full* modular group? In this case, I would expect the Rademacher series to produce an actual modular form, right? Also, in the reference you cite they deal with a specific Mock modular form, H. Does this apply to general modular forms, as the one above? [this is not at all clear to me, sorry]

Comment: The Dedekind eta function is not invariant under $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. It has a multiplier system.  Strictly speaking weight $1/2$ modular forms should be discusses in the context of the metaplectic group, a double cover of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$. The construction applies to a broad class of weight $1/2$ mock modular forms and modular forms.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(q)$ is lacunary and with coefficients only 0 and $\pm1$, it should be
trivial to prove that the asymptotics of the Fourier coefficients of
$j(q)f(q)$ are the same as those of $j(q)$ itself.

Comment: Dear Henri Cohen, I agree, but I am after an exact expression (not just the asymptotics), as one usually gets with Rademacher expansions.